# not suitable method found for add (Java)

Tags: java

Estoy intentado crear un pequeño programa que genera apuestas aleatorias a la Quiniela. Me da error en
 listaquiniela.add(objeto.generarapuesta());

Clase Quiniela

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quiniela {
    ArrayList < Apuesta > listaquiniela;

    public Quiniela() {
        listaquiniela = new ArrayList<Apuesta>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Apuesta> generarquiniela (int numero) {
        Apuesta objeto = new Apuesta();

        for (int i=0; i<numero; i++) {
            listaquiniela.add(objeto.generarapuesta());
        }
        return listaquiniela;
    }

    public void mostrarquiniela (){
        Apuesta objeto = new objeto();

        for (int i=0; i<listaquiniela.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(listaquiniela.get(i));
            }
    }
}
```

Clase Principal

```
import java.util.*;

public class Principal{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int numero = 0;
        String con = "S";
        Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            numero = escaner.nextInt();
            while (numero<2 || numero>8){
                System.out.println("Elija el número de apuestas");
                System.out.println("El mínimo son 2 y el máximo 8");
                numero = escaner.nextInt();
            }
            Quiniela apuesta = new Quiniela();
            apuesta.generarquiniela(numero);
            System.out.println("¿Desea realizar más apuestas?");
            System.out.println("S/N");
            con = escaner.nextLine();
        }while (con.equals("S"));
    }
}
```

Clase Apuesta

```
import java.util.*;

public class Apuesta {
    ArrayList<String>listaapuesta;

    public Apuesta(){
        listaapuesta=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<15; i++){
            listaapuesta.add(" ");
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> generarapuesta(){
        int v=0;
        Random objeto = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<listaapuesta.size(); i++){
            v=objeto.nextInt(3);

            if(v==0){
                listaapuesta.set(i, "x");
            }else{
                listaapuesta.set(i, v+"");
            }
        } return listaapuesta;
    }

    public String mostrarapuesta(){
        String resultado = "";
        for (int i=0; i<listaapuesta.size(); i++){
            resultado = resultado +" " +listaapuesta.get(i);

        }return resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has implementado `generarapuesta()`? El mensaje te está diciendo que de las muchas implementaciones hechas en la clase `Apuesta` no hay ninguna candidata que encaje con los valores de entrada y salida esperados (entrada `void` y salida `Apuesta`).

Comment: ¿qué devuelve `generarapuesta`?

Comment: Fíjate que `generarapuesta` devuelve `ArrayList<String>` y tu `listaquiniela.add(objeto.generarapuesta())` espera recibir un `Apuesta`.

Comment: @Ele, ¿cómo intentas usar `Apuesta` y `Quiniela`? ¿Quieres que arreglemos `Apuesta` para que sólo devuelva un resultado o una secuencia de ellos? ¿O quieres que arreglemos `generarquiniela` para que obtenga el listado y lo agregue a la quiniela?

Comment: Gracias por responder Oscar. Quiero arreglar Apuesta para que devuelva una secuencia de resultados. ¿Puedes mostrarme cómo implementarlo?

Comment: No puedo invitarte a un chat porque aún no tienes 15 de reputación. Pero me gustaría que explicaras qué define una apuesta. ¿Una única apuesta o una quiniela completa? Según me dices `Apuesta` devolvería todas las apuestas de una quiniela... ¿entonces para qué necesitas `quiniela`?

Comment: Me he explicado mal. Apuesta es el número de veces que un usuario decide rellenar la Quiniela.

Comment: Ele, gracias por tu paciencia. He ampliado mi respuesta para cubrir también algunos cambios en la clase `Principal`. Déjame un comentario en ella con cualquier duda que te surja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como te puse en los comentarios el mensaje de error viene provocado porque no encuentra ninguna implementación del método `generarapuesta` dentro de tu clase `Apuesta` que se ajuste a los valores de entrada (`void`) y de salida (`Apuesta`).

La forma en la que implementas la creación de `Apuesta`s y las guardas es incorrecta. Deberías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public ArrayList<Apuesta> generarquiniela (int numero) {
    for (int i=0; i<numero; i++) {
        /* Por cada quiniela rellena creo una instancia de "Apuesta" */
        Apuesta objeto = new Apuesta();
        /* Genero la apuesta */
        objeto.generarapuesta();
        /* Guardo la apuesta en nuestra lista de apuestas */
        listaquiniela.add(objeto);
    }
    /* Esto es innecesario, pero te lo mantengo por ahora */
    return listaquiniela;
}
```

Al finalizar la ejecución de `generarquiniela` se habrán guardado `n` apuestas en la lista `listaquiniela`.

Pero tal y como te pongo el código, necesitarás una pequeña modificación en la clase `Apuesta`.

En lugar de:

```
public ArrayList<String> generarapuesta(){
```

Usa:

```
public void generarapuesta(){
```

No necesitamos devolver la apuesta porque ésta se guarda internamente en la instancia, en la propiedad `listaapuesta`.

Por otro lado, habría que arreglar también `mostrarquiniela` de la siguiente manera:

```
public void mostrarquiniela (){
    /* Por cada apuesta de la lista llamamos a su método "mostrarapuesta" */
    for (int i=0; i<listaquiniela.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Quiniela Nº" + i);
            System.out.println(listaquiniela.get(i).mostrarapuesta());
        }
}
```

Y, por último, te queda adaptar `Principal` para que el texto que pregunta el número de apuestas salga antes de preguntarte el número y que tras generar la quiniela se muestre su contenido:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Principal{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int numero = 0;
        String con = "S";
        Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            do {
                System.out.println("Elija el número de apuestas");
                System.out.println("El mínimo son 2 y el máximo 8");
                numero = escaner.nextInt();
            } while (numero < 2 || numero > 8);
            Quiniela apuesta = new Quiniela();
            /* Generamos "numero" apuestas */
            apuesta.generarquiniela(numero);
            /* Las mostramos */
            apuesta.mostrarquiniela();
            System.out.println("¿Desea realizar más apuestas?");
            System.out.println("S/N");
            con = escaner.nextLine();
        }while (con.equals("S"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Falta modificar el mostrarquiniela () de Quiniela para que funcione correctamente con este codigo.

Comment: Cierto. Gracias por recordármelo, ahora estaba arreglando el Principal para que no se salga inmediatamente tras poner el número de apuestas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Oscar. Se han solucionado los errores :)

Comment: De nada @Ele, un placer. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta en el símbolo de marca `✓` que hay en la parte superior izquierda de mi respuesta para marcar como solucionada tu pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu método `generarapuesta()` retorna un `ArrayList` de `String` y se lo estas pasando a un `ArrayList` de `Apuesta`

Comment: Por favor, si no tienes una respuesta específica para la pregunta deberías consultar lo que te falte mediante comentarios. Evita responder con respuestas genéricas o no aplicables. Pásate por: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Gracias

Comment: me parece extraño que las dos respuestas que SI solucionan el problema, esten con un voto negativo (no entiendo porque) y que justamente tu @OscarGarcia estes diciendo que hacer. Que es lo malo de ambas respuestas???

Comment: Precisamente yo no soy el que pone negativos. Yo explico el motivo por el que las respuestas no son correctas, no las voto, doy la oportunidad de mejorarlas, corregirlas o retirarlas. Tan sencillo es demostrarlo como que me digas dónde quieres que ponga un negativo y te lo pongo. Si yo lo hubiera puesto previamente no podría agregar otro negativo más.

Comment: Es un problema de entendimiento, para el la Solucion es hacerle todo el ejercicio, para otros es indicarle donde esta su error y que pueda arreglarlo. Ambas son validas.

Comment: Al menos yo soy un usuario nuevo y todavía no tengo el privilegio de comentar en otros lugares asi que por eso mi respuesta anterior carecía de los requerimientos de ser una buena respuesta, pero despues de que argumentaran mas la pregunta pude dar una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de tipos.

generarApuesta() devuelve un ArrayList de String y lo estas intentando añadir a un ArrayList de Apuesta que es de tipo distinto.

Simplemente define listaQuiniela como ArrayList

```
ArrayList < String> listaquiniela;
```

y usa addAll en vez de all.

```
listaquiniela.addAll(objeto.generarapuesta());
```

Comment: Por favor, si no tienes una respuesta específica para la pregunta deberías consultar lo que te falte mediante comentarios. Evita responder con respuestas genéricas o no aplicables. Pásate por: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Gracias

Comment: Es la respuesta especifica a su error. No estoy comentando nada, estoy diciendole que es lo que falla en su programa que es lo que justo el OP pregunta

Comment: Eso ya lo puse en los comentarios. El usuario busca una solución a ese problema, tu respuesta no le ayuda en esa tarea. Por favor, pásate por el enlace que te proporcioné: _Lee la pregunta cuidadosamente. ¿Que es lo que se esta preguntando específicamente? **Asegurarte que tu respuesta incluya la solución a esto**._

Comment: No, el usuario pregunta porque falla y eso es lo que se le ha respondido. Corregirselo entero seria hacerle el ejercicio y ese no es el proposito de esta pagina.

Comment: @OscarGarcia entiendo tu postura pero estoy de acuerdo con Lithorell, ambos hemos señalado exactamente cual es el fallo, para corregirlo deberíamos volver a hacerle toda la clase `Apuesta` desde 0 y, por tanto, todo el ejercicio. Esto es lo más cercano a una solución que podemos ofrecerle.

Comment: Y yo vuelvo a insistir que le hemos solucionado el problema que es que le da un error. Solucionarselo entero es hacer todo su trabajo. Es como si yo vengo a preguntar porque un main solamente no me hace un sistema de ventanas y quiero que me lo den entero.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en que intentas igualar una ArrayList a una ArrayList y NO es lo mismo.

```
listaquiniela.add(objeto.generarapuesta());//Esto está mal
```

listaquiniela solo se puede igualar a una ArrayList. Así como tampoco puedes igualar ningún tipo de objeto a otro que no sea el mismo tipo. Ej: `int i = "hola mundo!";`